# nginx proxy_cookie_path with different domain attribute

Tags: nginx, cookies, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to proxy_pass a domain `www.example.com` to `www.otherdomain.com`. The proxy works as expected but I have a problem to set the correct cookies on `www.example.com` as well (I need a session cookie for this to work)

In my nginx.conf I have `proxy_cookie_path / "/; HTTPOnly; Secure";`. This proxies one of the cookie headers which has no domain attribute

`set-cookie: cookietest=1; Max-Age=315569520; Expires=Mon, 18-Nov-2030 08:58:02 GMT`

But not for the cookie with the domain attribute
`set-cookie: SESSIONID=sessionID; Domain=www.otherdomain.com; Path=/; HTTPOnly; Secureotherdomain; Secure; HttpOnly`
I guess the problem is the Domain attribute which is set to the example domain and thus rejected by my browser. Is there a way to either change this header to exclude the Domain attribute or another possibility to set this cookie to `www.example.com`?

Comment: Isn't [`proxy_cookie_domain`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_domain) what you are looking for? Also there is a [`proxy_cookie_flags`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_flags) directive (available only in nginx 1.19.3+).

Comment: I was missing ```proxy_cookie_domain```! Thank you! Did not know about this.